# Is "closed-form analysis" a field of study in math?

Tags: summation, closed-form

I have an interest in finding the closed-form of numbers such as the reciprocal Fibonacci constant and $\zeta(2n+1)$.

I always refer to this as closed-form analysis, but is there a formal name for this kind of study already?

Comment: You could call yourself a ["human algebra system"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).

Comment: A closed form also depends on which functions, etc, are defined/named giving a “manmade” component to what is a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Until now, "closed-form analysis" itself seems not to be a field of study in mathematics. It is part of the single fields of mathematics. There are a lot of mathematical articles that describe closed forms for single applications and are titled with the term "closed-form analysis".

Closed forms are treated e.g. at antiderivatives, differential equations, equations, functions, generating functions, inverses, numbers, series. There are some concepts and methods for closed-forms in these fields.

see e.g.:

[Wikipedia: Closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)

[Wikipedia: Closed-form expression - Closed-form number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Closed-form_number)

[Borwein, J.; Crandall, R.: Closed forms: What they are and why we care. Notices Amer. Math. Soc. 60 (2013) 50-65](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.360.618)

[Are there some techniques which can be used to show that a sum "does not have a closed form"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743544/are-there-some-techniques-which-can-be-used-to-show-that-a-sum-does-not-have-a/2329022#2329022)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)